# Почему не разворачивается проект на MODX на локальном сервере OpenServer?

Tags: modx, openserver

Мне нужно развернуть проект на MODX у себя на локалке в OpenServer.
Я проделываю следующие действия:

**1. Скачал файлы проекта с хостинга и добавил их в openserver.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**2. Скачал базу данных и импортировал ее в phpMyAdmin.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**3. Изменил пути в файлах:**

```
 1. config.core.php (в корневой папке сайта)
 2. /manager/config.core.php
 3. /connectors/config.core.php
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**4. Заменил данные в файле**
core/config/config.core.php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**5. Удалил папку cache**

Но после проделанных действий проект все равно не запускается, выдает ошибку: Site temporarily unavailable.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста где я могу допускать ошибку или посоветуйте гайд по разворачиванию проекта. Может я пути не правильно прописываю?
Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

в index.php есть код, который генерирует вашу ошибку:

> /* include the modX class */ if (!@include_once (MODX_CORE_PATH .
> "model/modx/modx.class.php")) {
> $errorMessage = 'Site temporarily unavailable';
> @include(MODX_CORE_PATH . 'error/unavailable.include.php');
> header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable');
> echo "Error 503: Site temporarily unavailable
>
> ## Error
> 503
>
> {$errorMessage}
>
> ";
> exit(); }

Отсюда видно, что MODX_CORE_PATH неверен, попробуйте указать пути полностью. Для OpenServer это так работает.

Answer (score 0):

Основные причины этой проблемы:

1. Неправильный путь до core
2. Неправильные данные для базы (логин, пароль, имя базы, пустая база)

Посмотри логи - core/cache/logs. При такой проблеме в логи валятся ошибки. Там бывает всякое, вплоть до того, что может быть пустая таблица modx_site_settings.
В общем, ответ там точно должен быть!